Space of eventually zero real sequences
Define
\begin{align*}
X\triangleq \{(x_1,x_2,\dots )\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}:\text{ All but finitely many of $x_n$ are $0$ }\}
\end{align*}
and let $S\subseteq X$ to be open if and only if for all $n,\{(x_1,\dots ,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: (x_1,\dots ,x_n,0,0,\dots )\in S\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider
\begin{align*}
B_n \triangleq \{x \in X: \Big( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}< \frac{1}{n}\text{ and }x_{n+k}=0\text{ for all }k\in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
S\triangleq X \setminus \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_n
\end{align*}
According to wikipedia, cl$_X(S)=X$, but I have a hard time proving this, not even $0\in \overline{S}$. Can you help me?

Edit: Confused by the way Wikipedia presents its material, I asked a "wrong" question. The question above is now corrected.

You're probably confused because you wrote the definition of $S$ wrong

$a_n=(1/n^{1.5},…,1/n^{1.5},0,0,…)\in S$ where the first $n$ terms are nonzero. Then $\lim a_n=0$

@Jakobian, Can you elaborate on how it is wrong?

@JohnFrank If you take $x_1 = 0, ..., x_n = 1/n, x_{n+1} = 0, ...$ for example then you should have $x\in S$ but not according to your definition

@Jakobian, I got it now. Is it appropriate if I change my question now?

Yes, I think it is appropriate.

@JohnFrank If by changing your question you mean that you want to correct the definition of $S$, then yes. If you mean something else, I am not sure.
